# Laravel Mail the from and replyTo are ignored in the received email

Tags: laravel, email

I have problem with the Laravel's Mail. I have nothing wrong with the source code to send an email. The email was sent but the email address of sender is mine instead of sender. It is the one in the config file. The replyTo was ignored also.

My code is as following:

```
Mail::send('appointments.emails.new_appointment', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($sender)
    {
        $message->from($sender['email'], $sender['name'])
            ->to('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Name')
            ->replyTo($sender['email'], $sender['name'])
            ->subject('Contact from ' . $sender['name']);
    });
```

I received an email with sender name and my email address. And, when I click on rely, it replys to myself. That means the replyTo didn't work. How can I fix that?

Sorry if my English is not so good.

Comment: Imagine if I wanted to send an email as `tommy.hoang@gmail.com` and I could just set it in a PHP script and send it. Would you like that?

Comment: I understand but at least the replyTo should work.